# can I run microsoft office 2010 suite from old laptop's hard drive through my new laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I have an old laptop that runs Windows 7 and microsoft office suite 2010 well but the keyboard is losing a few keys.

If I take out the hard drive from the old laptop and use it as an "external hard drive" to a Windows 10 laptop, can I launch the microsoft office suite 2010 (i.e. open a Microsoft WORD file or a Microsoft Excel) through the "external hard drive" from new Windows 10 laptop ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work.

One solution would be to download and run "Advanced Tokens Manager" (by Josh Cell software) on your old laptop. This will allow you to save a file containing your Office license details which, along with the software, needs to be copied to your new laptop.

On your new laptop, you can install Office 2010, run Advanced Tokens Manager again and  then restore your license. In the spirit of fairness, once you've done the transfer then you should uninstall Office from your old laptop.

This process isn't officially supported by Microsoft, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of Office, there would be many registry entries created that tell Windows where the programs are and what to do when they're invoked via shortcuts or by "starting" existing documents.

But Office 2010 has not been installed on the new computer, none of those entries was be in its registry.

So I think you could not use Office 2010 installed on the previous hard drive which is connected to your new PC as external hard drive.

If the installation CD and product key of Office 2010 are still available, I would suggest you [reinstall it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-office-2010-1b8f3c9b-bdd2-4a4f-8c88-aa756546529d) on the external drive. That will create the necessary registry entries.

But considering the speed, it's best to install it on the hard drive on motherboard, which is probably better than a USB-connected external drive.

For the activation, it's recommended to [contact Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) to transfer the license to a new PC.